# Rock paper scissors not executing winning conditions properly

Tags: python, if-statement

really quick problem I think its a dumb mistake I made. So anyway I never actually used multiple `or` and `and` in my codes, I started using it when dealing with data but I do a lot of errors, so I decided to run a rock paper scissors program using it and it the program exits without properly running the win condition. Here is my code, would appreciate any help!!

```
import random

def isWin(player,opponent):
    if (player=='p' and opponent=='r') or (player=='r' and opponent=='s') or (player=='s' and opponent=='p'):
        return True
    else:
        return False





def play_rps():
 resp='c'
 while resp.lower()!='n':
     user='x'
     while user not in ['r','s','p']:
         user = input("'r' for rock 'p' for paper 's' for scissors ")
         computer = random.choice(['r', 's', 'p'])
         print(f'You chose {user} and Computer chose: {computer} ')
 if computer == user:
     return 'Draw'
 elif isWin(user, computer):
     return 'You win!'
 return 'You lose!'

print(play_rps())
```

Comment: Works as is. If you're not seeing the output then wrap the main call in a print statement `print(play_rps())`.

Comment: Also not sure if you have it in your full code, but be sure to import the random library `import random` so that `random.choice` can work.

Comment: Yea random is imported of course, that's great thanks!

Comment: I edited my code, does it look right now?

Comment: You have to tell us if the code now works or not.

Comment: It does work fine, thanks a lot! Any way I can improve it?

Comment: I added two while loops, but I am running in for an infinite loop, what's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to print it.

When you use a `return`, it gives or assigns the function a value instead of printing it

```
import random

def isWin(player,opponent):
    if (player=='p' and opponent=='r') or (player=='r' and opponent=='s') or (player=='s' and opponent=='p'):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def play_rps():
    user=''
    user=input("'r' for rock 'p' for paper 's' for scissors ")
    computer=random.choice(['r','s','p'])
    if computer==user:
        return 'Draw'
    elif isWin(user,computer):
        return 'You win!'
    return 'You lose!'


print(play_rps())
```

Comment: Okay I added print statements for the if statements as well, it works now but before adding print statements it only showed 'Draw'

Comment: edited my code, does it look right?

Comment: @Jos Much Better

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to change the condition for outer `while loop`, therefor it goes in an infinite loop.

This should do the trick

```
import random

def isWin(player,opponent):
    if (player=='p' and opponent=='r') or (player=='r' and opponent=='s') or (player=='s' and opponent=='p'):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def play_rps():
 resp='c'
 while resp.lower()!='n':
     user='x'
     while user not in ['r','s','p']:
         user = input("'r' for rock 'p' for paper 's' for scissors ")
         computer = random.choice(['r', 's', 'p'])
         print(f'You chose {user} and Computer chose: {computer} ')
         recp = 'n'
 if computer == user:
     return 'Draw'
 elif isWin(user, computer):
     return 'You win!'
 return 'You lose!'

print(play_rps())
```